# How to import git project into Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, git, makefile

I have C++ make project on the git but I can't import it into Xcode. I clicked "check out an existing project" and then choose repo and enter username passwords then select branch and download path. At the end it opens folder of project then I clicked finish, thats it nothing happens.

When I open an empty project, I can see the git project on the "source control" tab but I can't import it. Can you guys help me?

Btw: I am deeply regret to buy mac.

Answer (score 1):

To import a git repo into XCode 8 you just need to go to SourceControl -> Check Out... 
There in the enter a repository location text field enter the full path of the git repository (e.g., https://github.com/your-log-in/repo-name.git

Then you will be prompt about where to save the local files, and you are good to go